# How to generate high-resolution heatmap using seaborn?

Tags: python, heatmap, seaborn

I have too many features (~100) for correlation, resulting in low resolution figure. How could I improve resolution?

```
sns.heatmap(Feature_corr, cbar = True,  square = True, annot=False,annot_kws={'size': 15},  cmap= 'coolwarm')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here. It does not really matter how many features you got. A heat-map square will consists of many pixels and there are no real problems to see here. Describe what's annoying you! It seems your data is kind of interesting / non-uniform which explain the bigger blocks and of course the captions are broken as too many. Apart from that nothing looks bad too me. Maybe you are asking about matplotlibs output of images in regards to compression??? A heatmap is not necessarily interpolated (i hope you know that; just to be sure)

Answer (score 12):

Call `figure` from `matplotlib.pyplot` before `heatmap` and set the image size with `figsize`, i.e.:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.figure(figsize=(15, 15)) # width and height in inches
sns.heatmap(Feature_corr, cbar=1, square=1, annot=0, annot_kws={'size': 15}, cmap= 'coolwarm')
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the figure parameters from Matplotlib makes it possible to modify the width, height, font size of axis labels, and dpi. Adjusting those values may help your image resolution.

Additionally, you can play with the parameter `annot_kws={"size": 8}` from `sns.heatmap()` to modify the values font size.

DPI represents the number of pixels per inch in the figure. Higher values of DPI improve the resolution.

### PREVIOUS

```
corr = df2.corr() #your dataframe
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="Blues", annot=True)
```

Result image without Matplotlib adjustments

[image: Result image without Matplotlib adjustments]

### With Matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

corr = df2.corr() #your dataframe

# figsize=(6, 6) control width and height
# dpi = 600, I 
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), 
           dpi = 600) 
 
# parameter annot_kws={"size": 8} control corr values font size
sns.heatmap(corr, cmap="Blues", annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 8})

plt.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelsize = 12) # x font label size
plt.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelsize = 12) # y font label size
```

Result:

[image: Example Image result with Matplotlib:]

Comment: Note, that the order here is crucial - you must insert plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi = 600) before the sns.heatmap so this works.